# Where can I see the list of administrators in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, administrator

I have Windows 7 Professional. I would like to see the users that have administrative access on my PC.

But I do not have administrative access to my PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the command prompt and type:

> net user

It will display a list of all the users who are present.

To see if a user is a administrator, type

> net user [username]

and look at the Local Group Memberships.

Comment: This does not include domain users granted admin rights on your computer.

Answer (score 5):

To get the list of local administrators from the command line:

```
net localgroup administrators
```

You don't need to have administrator rights to execute this command.

Comment: Re *"...a list of local administrators"*: Do you mean *"...the list of local administrators"*?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/7539-local-users-groups-manager-open.html

mmc compmgmt.msc

Who is member of Administrators groups that users has administrative access.

Comment: But I do not have administrative access in my PC.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Who is member of Administrators groups that users has administrative access."*?